# SSRS employee hierarchy report not sorting correctly under the same parent

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

As you see the children under EMPID=2 are not sorting properly.
[Employee Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8OwM.jpg)

[Employee table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siiVy.jpg)
[Employee Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htcME.jpg)

I set up parent/child relationship in GROUP PROPERTY. General -> Group on EMPID. On Advanced -> ParentID

Add column "LEVEL" with expression value -> =level()

I have tried to change dataset sorting order with empid or parent id, nothing work. Report still shows the same incorrect order.

The problem occurs when I tried to move to production. I used the same report and changed Datasource and Dataset and keep everything else the same. I noticed level column (Which contain "=level()" function shows 0. I think this is the root cause of the issue. Not sure why this function not working.

I created a new report on production server with the same query. No luck as well.

Comment: Please do not use images for code, data or errors use formatted/markdown text.

Comment: Maybe I have it backwards, but don't you want to sort by the Parent ID first, and then the Emp ID?  Also, your EmpID and ParentID are varchars, so 2 will be greater than 11.

Comment: Are you ordering in the query or in the report? The table's grouping has its own sort property.

Comment: @HannoverFist, no ordering in the query. Table grouping sort by function "level()". Somehow, extra column I added with "LEVEL" shows all 0. I think this is the root cause of the issue why the report not sorted properly.

Comment: @ourmandave, I tried to change data type to int as well. I thought varchar gives me blank space that causes mismatch. But data type is not the issue

Comment: I resolved the issue by casting the parent and child column to INT on the query.